# How to keep selected text of EditText when Edittext is clicked

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am developing an Application which have to look and function like default Browser of Android device. So I have an EditText being used to enter url .

So I want to make it work as when user clicks on EditText, want to select whole tet inside EditText and make it selected just like in search bar in browser.

I googled a lot but didnt find any solution.

I am able to select whole text by using

```
    txtSearchURL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((EditText) v).setSelection(0, txtSearchURL.getText()
                    .toString().length());
        }

    });
```

but it only shows it selected for a second but not making it selected .

So please help to make it happen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this programatically. In your layout XML add the following to your `EditText`:

```
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
```

E.g.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/editText"
          android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
          android:hint="@string/hint_text"

          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: i used it as well but it make text selected only first time when activity opens . but not again

Comment: It will select the text everytime the view REgains focus. You should check if the EditText ever loses focus so it can be regained (including text-selection) if you tap on it.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to do it programmatically (e.g., only if the user long-presses the EditText):

```
editText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
```

Comment: i used it as well but it make text selected only first time when activity opens . but not again

Comment: I just tested it and it worked perfectly both via xml and programmatically. If you don't find the reason it's not working in your code you could try forcing it at every click (dirty solution) by `editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 editText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
 }});` Also make sure to test with the original keyboard app (not with a custom keyboard).

Comment: The suggestion in the comment seems very dirty indeed.. find the root cause of your problem by investigating the focus behavior of your components. There's always some work-around but you will never get clean, maintainable and robust code that way.

Comment: Yes .. It seems problem is that EditText which is inside custom ActionBar is not getting focus...